# How to get GCC to warn about identifier name collisions?

Tags: c++, gcc, namespaces, g++, warnings

Here is a minimal example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> count;

int main() {
    int(count.size());
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling it with

```
$ \g++ --std=c++0x -ggdb -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -W -pipe \
       -mmmx -msse -msse2 -msse3 \
       -ftrapv -Wall -Wextra \
       -Wctor-dtor-privacy  -Wlogical-op    -Wnoexcept \
       -Woverloaded-virtual     -Wsign-promo    -Wstrict-null-sentinel \
       -Wstrict-overflow=5      -Wundef     -Weffc++   \
       -Wcast-align \
       -Wcast-qual      -Wchar-subscripts   -Wcomment \
       -Wconversion \
       -Wdisabled-optimization  -Wfloat-equal   \
       -Wformat  \
       -Wformat=2   -Wformat-nonliteral     -Wformat-security  \
       -Wformat-y2k     -Wimport    -Winit-self     -Winline \
       -Winvalid-pch    -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations  \
       -Wmissing-braces -Wmissing-field-initializers \
       -Wmissing-format-attribute       -Wmissing-include-dirs \
       -Wmissing-noreturn   -Wpacked    -Wpadded \
       -Wpointer-arith \
       -Wredundant-decls    -Wreturn-type   -Wsequence-point  \
       -Wshadow \
       -Wsign-compare   -Wstack-protector   \
       -Wstrict-aliasing \
       -Wstrict-aliasing=2  -Wswitch    -Wswitch-default \
       -Wswitch-enum        -Wtrigraphs     -Wuninitialized \
       -Wunknown-pragmas    -Wunreachable-code   \
       -Wvolatile-register-var  -Wwrite-strings -Wunused-parameter  \
       -Wno-parentheses d.cpp
```

i.e. most of the warning flags that I got from some other question, I get:

```
d.cpp: In function 'int main()':
d.cpp:7:5: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
     int(count.size());
     ^
d.cpp:7:5: error: expected ';' before 'int'

Status 1
```

Clearly, it got confused because `count` is declared in `<algorithm>`. But the error message doesn't reveal that.

It would be fine if there was a warning that the vector has the same name as a function. **Is there such a warning?**

Removing `using namespace std;` avoids the problem, but is there a warning that still works in the presence of `using namespace std;`? All it would have to do is keep track of symbols in the current context, which compilers already do, and issue a warning if a statement shadows or redeclares one. Seems like a simple feature, I can't believe it already doesn't do it.

Comment: If removing the `abusing namespace` directive solves the problem, then remove it. It does more harm than good anyway.

Comment: Well, thats what you get for importing multiple things into the same namespace. Thats why using namespace is generally not recommended.

Comment: No, I need it to be able to type faster. @PlasmaHH Are you sure that's the reason? Doesn't seem like a strong-enough reason to me.

Comment: I tried clang++ (had to `#include <vector>` first), it gives me the error `reference to 'count' is ambiguous` and then names all counts it found (i.e. `vector<int> count` and `std::count`).

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev Code is written once, but it's read, analysed and learned by humans many times over. Saving one second in typing `std::` once and adding about a minute to each reader's time to figure out what `count` means is *not* productive.

Comment: @Malloc (Added the `#include <vector>`, thanks.) In some cases, `g++` also says `error: reference to 'count' is ambiguous`, but with this particular line, it must unambiguously read it as the other `count`. Which is the puzzling thing.

Comment: @Angew You're absolutely right in general, but in my case the code will be read about once or twice, so it is productive. Also, I'm not advocating the use of `using namespace` here, the question is not about that. However, `using namespace std` in particular should be something that GCC makes convenient and safe in the future, because all those everyday things are used on every other line of code, and might as well be in the global namespace. It saves both typing and reading time to have less clutter from the `std::`s.

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev No, it's not clutter. The namespace exists for a reason, and it's actually self-documenting with that prefix (which is quite short). If I see `std::vector`, I know what it is. If I see just `vector`, I need to find out whether it's `std::vector`, `thrust::vector` or a custom X,Y,Z triplet.

Comment: @Angew In my project I can have a convention that `std` is always `using` and if anything collides with one of those names, there should be an error issued by the compiler, which will force us to correct it to `alien::vector` or use a different name for it. This sounds reasonable to me, because I've never seen any other `vector`, and thus the `std::` in front of it is redundant, which makes it appear as clutter if looking from behind my glasses.

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev Fair enough. If it's stressed enough in the project docs (and if all developers actually read those), it's a valid way to go.

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev - There are lots of very common names besides `vector` in the standard library. As you have discovered, `count` is another. There are many, many others. Why chance such collisions when you can entirely avoid the problem with a mere `std::` prefix?

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev: Since you are using GCC, you don't have much of a choice. Your project conventions will have to change.

Answer (score 2):

> Clearly, it got confused because count is declared in . But the error message doesn't reveal that.

Use something other than gcc and you'll see better error messages. The error messages from gcc have improved a bit, but that's not saying much. The error messages from gcc were notorious for lack of clarity. The message from clang is much clearer in this regard. It tells about two candidates that it cannot distinguish between, one being `count.size()` where "count" is the vector you have declared, and the other being `std::count.size()`, where `std::count` is defined in the header `<algorithm>`.

The solution to this particular problem is simple: Get rid of that `using namespace std` statement, and get rid of extraneous `#include` directives. It costs next to nothing to type `std::vector<int>` as opposed to `vector<int>`. Typing those extra five characters saves a whole lot of time downstream when the code needs to be understood and maintained by someone else. That "someone else" may well be you six months from now when you no longer understand what your code did.